# Can I look for incoming transactions with only my private view key?

Tags: daemon, monero-wallet-rpc

I have a wallet and without using Monero Wallet GUI, I want to check for incoming transactions every 5 minutes. For that, I will write code (in .NET), that will execute a method every 5 minutes.

What that method should do is currently unknown to me. As far as I know, I can check the blockchain for transactions with my private key. Is it possible or do I need more data than that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running `./monero-wallet-cli --generate-from-view-key <private view key>`, you can generate a view only wallet file.

Then you can run `./monero-wallet-rpc --wallet-file view-only-wallet --rpc-bind-port 18084` to launch the RPC wallet using your view only wallet file.

Then you can poll the wallet RPC method [get_transfers](https://www.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#get_transfers) with the field `in:true` to fetch incoming transactions.